# How to send data without refreshing page in laravel?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel

I need send data to the database without refreshing page.

**Home Blade :**

```
<form class="chat" id="message" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <li>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="message" class="" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class=" btn-success btn-sm searchButton" id="save" >
                    Send
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</form>
```

**Controller :**

```
public function message(Request $data)
{
    $ins = $data->all();
    unset($ins['_token']);
    $store = DB::table("chatbox")->insert([$ins]);
    return Redirect('Users/home')->with('message',"success");
}
```

**Ajax :**

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".save", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '/Users/message',
        data: $(".message").serialize(),
        success: function(store) {

        },
        error: function() {
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

At present when I send data it is automatically refreshing the whole page but only the particular form need to be refreshed.

Answer (score 4):

You should change the type of the button from `submit` to `button` like :

```
<button type="button" class=" btn-success btn-sm searchButton" id="save" >end</button>
```

Or prevent the default action (`submit`) using `e.preventDefault();` like :

```
$(document).on("click",".save",function(){
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent page from submiting
    ...
    ...
});
```

**NOTE :** Note also that you don't have button with class `save` but with id `save` so the event handler should looks like :

```
$(document).on("click", "#save", function(){
________________________^
```

Comment: but id we have save

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but since you've an id save the selector should be `#save` as my answer point, but in your original post you've class selector `.save` instead ...

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent the default form submission, and use the script instead

```
$(document).on("click", "#save", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default form Submission

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: '/Users/message',
        data: $("#message").serialize(),
        success:function(store) {
            location.href = store;
        },
        error:function() {
        }
    });

});
```

and instead of returning a redirect, return the url from the controller and let the script handle the redirect

```
public function message(Request $data)
{
    $ins = $data->all();
    unset($ins['_token']);
    $store = DB::table("chatbox")->insert([$ins]);
    session()->flash('message', 'success');
    return url('Users/home');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to handle function inside javascript/jquery form `submit` funtion and use `e.preventDefault()` to stop HTML to submit the form.

Try your ajax code in the below code type.

```
$('#message').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //your ajax funtion here
});
```

You can reset/refresh your form in success function

```
 $("#message").trigger("reset");
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `return Redirect('Users/home')->with('message',"success");` and just return an array like

```
return ['message' => 'success'];
```